# React-MD Toolbar Adding a Logo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Looking to add a logo to the react-md toolbar, but it doesn't support it.

Has anyone done this or have any advice on how to add it? I want to make a link to the homepage and haven't messed with the guts of react yet

Thanks all

- Zach

Answer (score 1):

There's a prop called toolbarChildren that allows you to add content after the title. Here's a link to the documentation: https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/navigation-drawers?tab=1#navigation-drawer-proptypes-toolbar-children

```
const ToolbarContentComponent = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>Link Here</div>
  );
 }
});

<NavigationDrawer toolbarChildren={<ToolbarContentComponent />}/>
```